# Possible to set a property of a control via function

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

Hello All,
Is it possible to set a value of a control property via a function as shown in the image?
Thnx

Comment: Yes, it is possible! Tell us a bit more about what you're trying to achieve (i.e. what language are you programming in) and, possibly, show us something that you've tried, and you will most likely get one or more good answers.

Comment: Thnx for your comment. Trying to do it in Visual Studio .net Winform 4.5.1. I tried putting an = and a function name that returns a global variable but it doesn't work.